# Conversion of word file to HTML and after some edit in HTML convert it back to docx

Tags: c#, office-interop

I am working on a utility where users come and upload a word document to the application and assign to some specific persons, after assignment the specific users will come to application and will suggest some changes as well as do some formatting by their own and save it. And now anyone can download that recently updated file for their reference.

What I am doing for achieving this is - 
Step 1- While user is uploading the word file (docx/doc), my code is converting it to HTML file using below code -

```
object FileName;
object MissingType = Type.Missing;
object ReadOnly = false;
object IsVisible = false;
object DocumentFormat = 8; 

//Original file location where my application is uploaded the document for future reference
FileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WordFilePath"].ToString() + item.GUID + item.DocumentExtention;

//HTML file location where the application will save the file as html   
object HtmlDirectoryPath =   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HtmlFilePath"].ToString() + item.GUID +  ".htm";


//Conversion process
ApplicationClass ApplicationClass = new ApplicationClass();
ApplicationClass.Documents.Open(ref FileName, ref ReadOnly, ref MissingType,
                  ref MissingType, ref MissingType, ref     MissingType,
                  ref MissingType, ref MissingType, ref MissingType,
                  ref MissingType, ref IsVisible, ref MissingType,
                  ref MissingType, ref MissingType, ref MissingType,
                  ref MissingType);
ApplicationClass.Visible = false;
Document Document = ApplicationClass.ActiveDocument;
Document.SaveAs(ref HtmlDirectoryPath, ref DocumentFormat, ref MissingType,
                ref MissingType, ref MissingType, ref MissingType,
                ref MissingType, ref MissingType, ref MissingType,
                ref MissingType, ref MissingType, ref MissingType,
                ref MissingType, ref MissingType, ref MissingType,
                ref MissingType);
Document.Close(ref MissingType, ref MissingType, ref MissingType);
```

Note: - What above code will do, it will convert the doc file into HTML and saving it the specified location with the file as well as its supported files into the folder. [Just like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9Vao.jpg)

Step 2: Now user will update the text and for doing so I am using rangy highligher. User can update the text, highlight the text into this html file and save it back.[This all is working fine]

Step 3: Now comes to the most difficult thing, anytime any user can come and may download the latest file from server. So my job is now to convert the HTML back to word file and promt a download alert. 
I have tried to do this using the above code but it says that, applicationclass is unable to open the specified file and when I tried to read and write the new file using bytearray, the downloaded file says "unable to open, some data is corrupt"

Note: Simple word files are converting to and from HTML but when it comes to the complex word document which is having images and other things in it then the above error start to raise.

```
string FilePathHTML = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HTMLFilePath"] + ObjDocument.GUID + ".htm";
        //object FileHTMLPathTemp = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HTMLFilePath"] + "temp\\" + ObjDocument.GUID + ".htm";
        string FilePathTemp = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HTMLFilePath"] + "temp\\" + GUID + ".doc";


        StreamReader objReader;
        objReader = new StreamReader(FilePathHTML);
        string content = objReader.ReadToEnd();

        var path = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LivePathWithContent"] + "documents/html/" + ObjDocument.GUID + "_files";
        content = content.Replace(ObjDocument.GUID + "_files", System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LivePathWithContent"] + "documents/html/" + ObjDocument.GUID + "_files");

        StreamWriter objWriter = new StreamWriter(FilePathTemp);
        objWriter.Write(content);
        objWriter.Close();

        string contentType = "";
        if (ObjDocument.DocumentExtention.ToLower().Replace(".docx",".doc") == ".doc")
        {
            contentType = "application/msword;charset=utf-8";
        }
        else
        {
            contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
        }
        //byte[] arrBytes = FileToByteArray(FilePathHTML.ToString());
        //System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(FilePathTemp.ToString(), arrBytes); // Requires System.IO

        return File(FilePathTemp.ToString(), contentType, ObjDocument.DocumentName.Replace(".docx", ".doc"));
```

Please find the sample DOC files on cloud server https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_wGZDVWpHQcaEhMMWpMNXFMT1U&usp=sharing

Comment: In your place, the first thing I'd do would be to download one of these HTML files and try opening it in Word directly, without all the processing your code is doing, to see if you get the same error. I'd also want to see what value you're passing in the variable `DocumentFormat` when saving the document to HTML before offering any opinion.

Comment: `object DocumentFormat = 8; `

Comment: @CindyMeister  `object DocumentFormat = 8; ` Also please fine the HTML files after conversion from Word on the location [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_wGZDVWpHQcT19YUHRqdS1zVVE/view?pref=2&pli=1)

Comment: No, I'm not downloading your files and opening them on my system. I mean *you* should try it.

Comment: Is there anything anyone needs to more clarification, i am still struggling on this And have no answer.    @CindyMeister -  Do you need more information on this?

Comment: You still haven't run the test I suggested, as far as I can see. And, as I said, no one is going to download and open your files.

Comment: Sorry about the permissions. Now I have shared the files for everyone. Please have a look and let me know if this helps.

Comment: @CindyMeister - Could you please help me on this?